# Auto Increment Problem in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I created a table and set a field to auto increment some thing like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 123456;
```

But to some reason i deleted some of the rows in the table.

Now the question is when i insert new rows in the table the new rows should be assigned id's of the rows which have been deleted rather than assigning new id's.

I do not want to reset all the id's

How can i do this??

Help appreciated:)

Comment: You COULD reset the autoincrement number, but you really shouldn't need to. There should be no problem in non linear ids, should there?

Comment: Hey sorry i did not mention previously i do not want to reset ..

Comment: Wait. You have an auto-increment field. It starts a cap. You want it to continue at a lower number. but you don't want to reset it? Mind you I mean re-Set. Not reset it to 0 per se. Just reset it to whatever you want it....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry to say, but that is not the use of `AUTO_INCREMENT.`  If you want to re-use id's, then you would have to write your own trigger functions, and doing this is generally considered bad practice.

Imagine you were on id 50,000, and deleted an entry with id 1... would you really want the next record you add to re-use id 1?

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of AUTO_INCREMENT is to auto increment...

You can explicitly assign these ids though and mysql will allow it.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to do this manually rather than rely on MySQL to do it for you. The AUTO-INCREMENT flag keeps an integer that is incremented upon every insert statement and is assigned as the PK of the subsequent insert. Unless you want to write an update trigger that resets this value to the lowest non-used integer, I would suggest processing this in a server-side scripting language.

In any case, though, why is using the auto increment value a problem?

Answer (score 0):

To reset the autoincrement value, you can use

```
ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

The next inserted record will use ID 1.

Comment: Actually, the next ID would be (the maximum ID there is in the table) + 1.

Comment: No. The purpose of setting `AUTO_INCREMENT` is to change the next generated value.

Comment: You're right about the purpose, of course. But my comment was about what would actually happen. The statement that you wrote, "ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1", would reset the auto_increment counter to 1 only and only in case if the table is empty. If there are ANY records in the table (which is the case in the original question), after executing your statement, the counter will be set to {[the maximum ID there is in the table] + 1} if it's MyISAM. For InnoDB, the value of auto_increment won't be changed. Refer to official documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Actually, for both MyISAM and InnoDB you can change the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value if the value you pick is higher than the maximum defined ID. However, this obviously doesn't solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be something you're after.

`alter table Users AUTO_INCREMENT=0;`

This will reset the `auto_increment` back to `0 +` whatever the current highest id is.

*if you have `30`, your next entry would be `31`*